# What are the different types of database?

Tags: sql, json, database

Is it possible to classify the different types of database with the followings categories :

- tabular database (I don't know if it is the correct term): they can be stored in csv files. And we can do SQL on this data.
- nested database: for example json, xml, geojson
- network database: I don't if there are examples of files with a certain extension for this type of data

The data can be converted from one format to another, of course. But it is correct to have these categories ?

Comment: Obviously, you are not asking it out the blue,What is your real question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not correct categorization. Let's review your three types :

**Tabular** : Maybe you point to **RDBMS(Relational DBMS)** or SQL-Based

**Nested** : Maybe you mean **No-SQL or No-Relational** databases.

**Network** : I really don't know what you mean! But there is a technique in DBMS's that distribute data files on more than one system.

Read [this](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/database-management-system). Maybe it gives you more accurate view about databases.